# Extracting python list values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, json, list

I have a column in MySQL database which contains a `python list` of `json` formatted values like below:

| Column |
| --- |
| [{"name":"me","color":"red"} , {"name":"you","color":"blue"}] |

I could not use `json_extract()` function because it's not formatted exactly as a `json`

I want to extract each of `json` formatted in a new column like below:

| First_column | Second_column |
| --- | --- |
| {"name":"me","color":"red"} | {"name":"you","color":"blue"} |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use JSON_EXTRACT on the sample column included in your question:

```sql
SET @column = '[{"name":"me","color":"red"} , {"name":"you","color":"blue"}]';

SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(@column, '$[0]') AS First_column,
    JSON_EXTRACT(@column, '$[1]') AS Second_column;
```

Outputs:

| First_column | Second_column |
| --- | --- |
| {"name": "me", "color": "red"} | {"name": "you", "color": "blue"} |

Comment: I checked it with your [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UyAlw9N8) and it seems fine. Maybe OP was having some other issue.

Comment: My  db<>fiddle  is correct; but a way long process. Yours should be marked as an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The following query with combination of string manipulation functions `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, `REPLACE` and `CONCAT`shall get you the expected result.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('{', REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`column`, '}', 1), '{', -1), '\\"', '"'), '}') AS First_column,
  CONCAT('{', REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`column`, '}', 2), '{', -1), '\\"', '"'), '}') AS Second_column
FROM mytable;
```

Here is [a working demo using DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/TfXymyE4)

This gives me expected output as :

| First_column | Second_column |
| --- | --- |
| {"name":"me","color":"red"} | {"name":"you","color":"blue"} |

Please replace the `mytable` with your_actual_table_name and `column` with your actual column name. I have surrounded column with backticks as column is a reserved keyword in sql.